# Getting error for python libraries while installing GRR Incident response in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I am trying to install GRR Incident Response on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
While installing the deb package "grr-server_3.4.2-3_amd64.deb". I get below errors:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Can anybody please provide solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I'm working in a `conda` environment and
after trying endlessly updating both `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` without success, I looked for other solutions.

What did the trick for me was creating a soft link pointing to the `python` dir inside my conda environmet:

```
sudo ln -s $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6
```

Also don't forget to unset the `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` variables.